# Dagger 2: Injecting to Activities from multiple subcomponents

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

[This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html#android_dagger) shows how to inject dependencies into activities using Dagger 2's `AndroidInjectionModule` - on a very simple example. My use case is a bit more complicated:

- `App extends Application implements HasDispatchingActivityInjector`,
- `ActivityOne` which gets initialised using `ActivityModule`. Using this activity, the dependency `DepOne` is created,
- `ActivityTwo` which has a dependency `DepTwo` that cannot be correctly initialised without a preexisting `DepOne`.

The solution I came up with is:

- Create an `AppComponent` as the main component of the application,
- Create a `ComponentTwo` as a subcomponent of `AppComponent`. Add it at runtime, as soon as `DepOne` is available, and provide `DepTwo` in it,
- Inject to `ActivityTwo` within `ComponentTwo`.

This, however, requires that the `ActivityModule`, which currently looks like this:

```
@Module(subcomponents = {
    ActivityOneSubcomponent.class,
    ActivityTwoSubcomponent.class
})
public abstract class ActivityModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(ActivityOne.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> bindLoginActivityInjectorFactory(ActivityOneSubcomponent.Builder builder);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(ActivityTwo.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> bindWorldActivityInjectorFactory(ActivityTwoSubcomponent.Builder builder);
}
```

be split into two distinct modules, one for `ActivityOne` and bound with `AppComponent`, and the other one for `ActivityTwo` (and other future activities) bound with `ComponentTwo`.

I did that, but Dagger protests at runtime when trying to inject to `ActivityTwo`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<ActivityTwo>
```

It seems like the application can't see the injector factory provided by the added subcomponent.

Any ideas/hints?

---

Edit: I'm posting the reproducing code below as requested (there are actually no Dagger-injectable properties there, as I scraped them away):

**ActivityOne.java**

```
public class ActivityOne extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        enterPartTwo();
    }

    private void enterPartTwo() {
        App.app(this).makeComponentTwo();
        ActivityTwo.start(this);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**ActivityOneModule.java**

```
@Module(subcomponents = {
        ActivityOneSubcomponent.class
})
public abstract class ActivityOneModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(ActivityOne.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> bindActivityOneInjectorFactory(ActivityOneSubcomponent.Builder builder);
}
```

**ActivityOneSubcomponent.java**

```
@Subcomponent
public interface ActivityOneSubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<ActivityOne> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<ActivityOne> {}
}
```

**ActivityTwo.java**

```
public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_world);
    }

    public static void start(Context from) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(from, ActivityTwo.class);
        from.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**ActivityTwoModule.java**

```
@Module(subcomponents = {
        ActivityTwoSubcomponent.class
})
public abstract class ActivityTwoModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(ActivityTwo.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> bindActivityTwoInjectorFactory(ActivityTwoSubcomponent.Builder builder);
}
```

**ActivityTwoSubcomponent.java**

```
@Subcomponent
public interface ActivityTwoSubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<ActivityTwo> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<ActivityTwo> {}
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application implements HasDispatchingActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    AppComponent appComponent;
    ComponentTwo componentTwo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create();
        appComponent.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }

    public void makeComponentTwo() {
        componentTwo = appComponent.inGameComponent()
                .build();
    }

    public static App app(Context context) {
        return (App) context.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ActivityOneModule.class,
        AndroidInjectionModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(App app);

    ComponentTwo.Builder inGameComponent();
}
```

**ComponentTwo.java**

```
@ScopeTwo
@Subcomponent(modules = {ActivityTwoModule.class})
public interface ComponentTwo {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        ComponentTwo build();
    }
}
```

**ScopeTwo.java**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ScopeTwo {
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.abc, PID: 5923
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abc/com.example.abc.ActivityTwo}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<com.example.abc.ActivityTwo>
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<com.example.abc.ActivityTwo>
   at dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.inject(DispatchingAndroidInjector.java:105)
   at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:61)
   at com.example.abc.ActivityTwo.onCreate(ActivityTwo.java:22)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Hope it helps answer the question.

Comment: Make sure that you added your `ActivityTwoAndOthersModule` to your `ComponentTwo`, and that your `ActivityTwoSubcomponent` is registered as a subcomponent to the `ActivityTwoAndOthersModule` as well. Looks like you miss some part of an annotation somewhere. If you did check and did not find anything please provide the actual code

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I checked the code and everything seemed all right to me. I reduced it to a minimum reproducing example and will post it in a sec.

Comment: I have an idea about how to pull this off, but you'll first of all need the HasActivityInjector (i.e. not dispatching, so you can provide your own implementation) in Dagger 2.11. Before I do, though: How do you want your app to function if someone intents into ActivityTwo before ActivityOne? That would mean you can't create DepTwo, because DepOne hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of this app as having a single well-defined entry point... so I did not think about it at all. Is this something I definitely should consider anyway?

Comment: @JeffBowman I'm really keen to get to know your answer :)

Comment: @pstobiecki, can you post the project on github?

Comment: What is the scope of dependency 1? If it is ActivityScope and Act1 gets killed the app will crash! I'm not sure what Act2 needs from Act1 in order to work but, this difficulty in initialization is an indication of high coupling between these two classes. Let us know what dep1 and dep2 are and perhaps it could be redesign in order to provide, at least dep1, as App scope.

Answer (score -2):

Make ActivityTwo implement HasSupportFragmentInjector

```
public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity implements HasSupportFragmentInjector {

@Inject
DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
AndroidInjection.inject(this);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Inject
DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;

@Override
public AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
    return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;
}
} // end of class
```

Secondly, your boilerplate codes are way too much for a small implementation. Use @ContributesAndroidInjector to create subComponents for your activities. Use this post for the easiest implementation of this https://medium.com/@idee4ril/dagger-2-11-with-android-a606c132826c